# How to solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + xy$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this as linear differential equation but integrating factor is like an error function. I tried in other methods but there is no result. Please mention the solution if you know.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+xy$$

Comment: The solution to this equation should be unique for any given initial condition, so if one method gives you an error function then any other valid method should also give you an error function. So you're going to have to deal with the error function if you want the solution.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks for pointing out the error. We would still get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27+-+yx+%3D+1) involving the $erf$ function, and from your comment on uniqueness we are unlikely to have an elementary solution.

Comment: Is the solution not simply $y(x)=c_1e^{x^2/2}+e^{x^2/2}\int_0^{x/\sqrt{2}}e^{-t^2}\,dt\,$ ? Sure, one can write this in terms of erf if one wishes but it is still one unique solution.

Comment: @KurtG. It is  definitely correct, the OP wants to avoid error functions but it won't be possible looking at your representation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an advanced approach, I don't know if this could help. Let $u=u(x,y)$. Using the characteristic method for solving PDE, we have $\frac{u_x}{u_y}=-\frac{dy}{dx}=-(1+xy)$. This implies that
\begin{align}
u_x+(1+xy)u_y
=0 \qquad\qquad (1)
\end{align}
Assume that $u(x,y):={\rm{e}}^{\alpha x + \beta y}$ is a solution; where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary constants. Substitute in the equation $(1)$, we get
\begin{align}
\alpha {\rm{e}}^{\alpha x + \beta y}+\beta(1+xy) {\rm{e}}^{\alpha x + \beta y}=\left[\alpha+\beta(1+xy)\right] {\rm{e}}^{\alpha x + \beta y}=0
\end{align}
but ${\rm{e}}^{\alpha x + \beta y}\ne 0$ for all $x,y$ and $\alpha,\beta$. So that we have $\alpha+\beta(1+xy)=0$
\begin{align}
\alpha=-\beta(1+xy) \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad(2)
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
u(x,y):={\rm{e}}^{\alpha x + \beta y}= {\rm{e}}^{-\beta(1+xy) x + \beta y}= {\rm{e}}^{-\beta(x+x^2y) + \beta y}
\end{align}
which gives an implicit solution of the D.E.

---